# C++ - Do derived classes inherit static members of the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

I've got a base class GameObject that has a member

```
static Cell **grid;
```

I've also got a derived class Character which is the base class for another class Player. So my question is: will all objects of GameObject, Character, and Player classes have access to that same grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Player` *is a* `Character`, which *is a* `GameObject`.  So yes, they all have access to the static `grid`.

...Subject to access protection of course (as pointed out by Sam).  So you need to declare `grid` within a `public` or `protected` region for this to be true, and furthermore, you would need to declare the inheritance using `protected` or `public` modes:

```
class GameObject
   {
protected:
   static Cell **grid;
   };

class Character : protected GameObject
   {
   };
```

Comment: If `Character` inherits privately from `GameObject`, it will still have access to `GameObject::grid`.   Classes derived from `Character` would not have access.

Answer (score 1):

The rules for whether the static class members of a base class are available to the immediately derived class, the most derived class, or any other class in between, in the class hierarchy depends on:

- whether the static class member is public, protected, or private.
- and, in the inheritance chain, whether each class inherits the base class as a public class, protected class, or a private class.

So the answer to your question is: depends. Depends on these factors.

Comment: Sorry. I should've added that it's a protected member of the base class

Comment: And the derived classes inherit publicly from their respective base classes

Comment: A class that derives publicly, or protectedly (is that even a word?) inherits protected members of the base class, and they are protected in the derived class. A class that derives privately inherits protected members of the base class, and they are private in the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that unless you explicitly use the **protected** modifier, this property would be considered private. In your example, you didn't prefix it with either **protected** or **public**, so it would be considered private and hence not accessible in the derived classes.

Comment: That depends on whether the class was declared with `class` or `struct` keyword.